# Cursor.next() never resolves using Mongoose (4.13.19)

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'm attempting to use a cursor:

```
const cursor = Thing.find({}).cursor();
cursor.next().then((a,b) => { console.log(a); console.log(b); })
```

But this never resolves; it just sits there. There doesn't seem to be a `cursor.exec()` or anything like that. `cursor.close()` even throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of null`.

All the documentation I can find ignores this and just goes about its example, thus implying I don't need it. But I quite obviously do, as it doesn't actually load any documents from Mongo.

This is on a legacy project and I'm unable to change the version of Mongoose. Node is 8.15.0, MongoDB is 3.2, and both are in a similar boat.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, look, I'm going to own up to my stupidity here and admit that I hadn't actually connected to mongo before attempting to load the data. I'm also going to leave this question up as a combination of reference and penance.

Though to be fair I have no idea why mongoose wouldn't tell me it's not connected instead of blocking on a nonexistent connection. But I still should have known.